# Screen resolution iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I'm new in the development app for iPhone.
I'm currently developing an app to run on all iPhones, but I'm having a problem when i change emulator the position of button change completely like the screen in below the form.
If anyone knows any solution to maintain uniform screen, i would appreciate the help

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes and i use xcode 6.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are using AutoLayout, it looks like your constraints may be wrong. It seems like each row of your keypad is constrained top and bottom based on its distance from nearest neighbors.

However in this case you probably just want to constrain the bottom to the nearest neighbor and set an explicit height constraint.

Answer (score -1):

One word -------> AutoLayout.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Are you sure you need to be so verbose? I'm sure you can shave this answer down a few more bytes.

Comment: There's always room for efficiency. ;)